# Stopping Symfony 2 configuration processor from adding an empty array?

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

With the following configuration tree:

```
$rootNode
    ->fixXmlConfig('parameter')
    ->children()
        ->arrayNode('parameters')
            ->useAttributeAsKey('name')
            ->prototype('array')
                ->children()
                    ->scalarNode('type')->end()
                    ->scalarNode('value')->end()
                ->end()
            ->end()
        ->end()
    ->end();
```

... even if I do not specify the `parameters` key, Symfony is adding an empty array:

```
$config = $processor->processConfiguration($configuration, array());
var_dump($config); // Output is array('parameters' => array())
```

But I want the `parameters` key unset, absent, if there are not parameters.

I've tried deleting the key (if empty) in `beforeNormalization`, but it doesn't work:

```
$rootNode
    ->beforeNormalization()
        ->always(function ($v) {
            if(empty($v['parameters'])) {
                unset($v['parameters']);
            }

            return $v;
        })
```

Seems that with an empty array the before normalization callback is never executed.

Answer (score 0):

Array node will ensure that normalized value of configuration key will always be array and nothing else, even nothing is provided (in this case you get an empty array).

Instead of trying to get rid of this key in returned result of configuration processor, I think, it would make more sense to handle this config item (which always will be array) after processing is done. For example, you can unset it if it is empty.

```
$config = $processor->processConfiguration($configuration, array());
if(empty($config['parameters'])) {
    unset($config['parameters']);
}
```

Comment: The problem is I have to perform some validation inside the configuration itself, and I need to check if parameters is empty or not.

Comment: It looks to me, that normalization and validation callbacks are not run if configuration key is not provided. You can add `isRequired()` to your array node definition to ensure, that configuration key is provided. Maybe this can help?

Answer (score 0):

Gremo, you've almost made it work. You tried `beforeNormalization`, but `parameters` key is the result of normalization, so it apears AFTER normalization. So we should use some finalization routine such as:

```
$rootNode->validate()
    ->always(function($val) {
        if (empty($val['parameters'])) {
            unset($val['parameters']);
        }

        return $val;})
    ->end()
```

Answer (score 0):

To my mind you should just use the treeBuilder NodeDefinition API to say that is should be null if not set:

```
$rootNode
    ->fixXmlConfig('parameter')
    ->children()
        ->arrayNode('parameters')
            ->useAttributeAsKey('name')
            ->prototype('array')
                ->children()
                    ->scalarNode('type')->end()
                    ->scalarNode('value')->end()
                ->end()
            ->end()
                ->defaultNull() /////// defaults to null OR
                ->setAddIfNotSet(false) 
        ->end()

    ->end();
```